# Let $(A,+, \cdot)$ be a ring with the given tables, determine which is the zero and inverse of each element

Tags: abstract-algebra, binary-operations

Let $(A,+, \cdot)$ be a ring with the given tables for operations $+$ and $\cdot$

\begin{array}{c|cccc}
 + & s & t & x & y \\ \hline
 s & y & x & s & t \\
 t & x & y & t & s \\  
 x & s & t & x & y\\
 y & t & s & y & x\end{array}

\begin{array}{c|cccc}
 \cdot & s & t & x & y \\ \hline
 s & y & y & x & x \\
 t & y & y & x & x \\  
 x & x & x & x & x\\
 y & x & x & x & x\end{array}

determine:
a) which is the zero of the ring
b) the inverse of each element;

for a) what I can see is that $x$ act as element $0$ for $+$

also $x$ act as element $0$ for $\cdot$ but  for $y$ the result equals $x$ too

for b) $s+t=x$ so if $x=0$ then $s$ is inverse of $t$

in $\cdot$ I can't see how is $s\cdot s= s \cdot t =y$, because as said before $s$ and $t$ is inverse of each other...

I would appreciate if someone can give some insight on how to solve this problem

Comment: $y$ does not act as $0$ element for $\cdot$, because $y\cdot s=x$, not $y$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner sorry what I mean is that it gives the same result, gonna edit that

Comment: $A$ does not have a multiplicative identity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x$ is the additive identity.

The additive inverses are $-s=t,-t=s,-x=x,-y=y$.

This isn't a ring with unit.

Comment: usually an additive inverse would be denoted $-s$ rather than $s^{-1}$

Comment: @J.W. Tanner I guess you're right.